# ¿Cómo puedo pintar las celdas de una tabla según las combinaciones encontradas PHP MVC?

Tags: php, mvc

Buen día a todos, estoy realizando un script para **calcular** las **combinaciones** posibles en base a dos columnas de una tabla y las filas enviadas por el formulario, este resultado se debe mostrar de manera visual pintando las celdas de cada tabla sin repetir el orden, en la imagen 1 me brinda el resultado correcto, tengo el problema al pintar las demás celdas del resultado 2 en adelante, adjunto la captura de mi Excel referencial.
Si conocen de alguna documentación u orientación sería de mucha ayuda, el script está desarrollado en PHP MVC

```
/*template.controller.php*/

/*Función para crear las tablas*/
static public function fncComb($chars, $size, $combinations = array()) {

    if (empty($combinations)) {
        $combinations = $chars;
    }

    if ($size == 1) {
        return $combinations;
    }

    $new_combinations = array();

    foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
        foreach ($chars as $char) {
            $new_combinations[] = $combination .'.'. $char;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($size)) {
        return TemplateController::fncComb($chars, $size - 1, $new_combinations);
    }

}

/*Función para crear las tablas*/
static public function createTable($rows, $tables) {

    $count = 1;
    $s = '';
    $dato=[[]];
    $celdas=$rows;
    $tabla=0;
    $col=0;
    for ($iT=0; $iT < $tables*2; $iT++) { 
        $s .= '<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 scroll">';
        $s .= '<table class="table shadow-inset table-hover table-bordered">';
        /*Cabecera*/
        $counter = $count++;
        $s .= '<thead>';
        $s .= '<tr>';
        $s .= '<th class="text-center col1" colspan="2">'.$counter.'</th>';
        $s .= '</tr>';
        $s .= '</thead>';
        /*Cuerpo*/
        $s .= '<tbody>';
        $h=0;
        $f=0;
        $c=0;
        for ($iR=0; $iR < $rows ; $iR++) {
            $s .= '<tr>';
            $f=$iR;
            for ($m=0; $m < 2; $m++) {
                $h++;
                $c=$m;
                if ($iT==$iR) {
                    $col=1;
                } else {
                    $col=0;
                }
                if (($iR==$f) and ($m<>$col)) {
                    $s .= '<td class="text-center" id="celda" style="background:#FFFF00" >'.$iR.$m.'</td>';
                    $dato[$iR][$m]='X';
                } else {
                    $s .= '<td class="text-center" id="celda" style="background:none" >'.$iR.$m.'</td>';
                }
            }
            $s .= '</tr>';
        }
        $s .= '</tbody>';
        $s .= '</table>';
        $s .='</div>';
    }
    return $s;
    
}
```

/*home.controller.php*/

class HomeController{

```
public function combinations() {

    $action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';

    if ($action == 'ajax') {
        
        if (isset($_POST["numRows"])) {

            /*Validamos la sintaxis de los campos*/

            if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,5}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/', $_POST["numRows"] )) {

                /*Realizamos el conteo de combinaciones*/

                $chars = array('yellow', 'none');
                $output = TemplateController::fncComb($chars, $_POST["numRows"]);
                $countComb = count($output);

                echo '<div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <span id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Total de combinaciones: 
                            <b>'.$countComb.'</b>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mb-3">';

                /*Creamos las tablas con la cantidad de combinaciones posibles*/

                $creaTabla = TemplateController::createTable($_POST["numRows"], $countComb/2);
                echo $creaTabla;

                echo '</div>';

                if ($countComb > 0) {
                    
                    /*Cerramos el loader*/

                    echo '<script>

                        fncFormatInputs();
                        matPreloader("off");
                        fncSweetAlert("close", "", "");

                    </script>';

                }

            } else {

                /*Cerramos el loader y mostramos la alerta*/

                echo '<script>

                    fncFormatInputs();
                    matPreloader("off");
                    fncSweetAlert("close", "", "");
                    fncNotie(3, "Error de sintaxis de campo");

                </script>';
                
            }

        } else {

            echo '<div class="row justify-content-center">

                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
                        <div class="card bg-primary shadow-soft border-light px-4 py-1 mb-6">
                            <div class="card-body text-center text-md-left">
                                <div class="row align-items-center">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <h2 class="mb-3">No hay datos para mostrar</h2>
                                        <p class="mb-4">Ingrese un valor en el formulario para visualizar las combinaciones.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0 text-md-right">
                                        <img src="views/assets/img/welcome.png" height="200" alt="illustration">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>';

        }

    }

}
```

}

[image: Resultado 1 (número de filas 1, combinaciones 2 (ok))]

[image: Resultado 2 (número de filas 2, combinaciones 4 (tabla 1 y 2 ok, tabla 3 y 4 repite))]

[image: Resultado 5 (número de filas 5, combinaciones 32 (tabla del 1 al 5 ok, tabla 7 en adelante repite))]

[image: Excel referencial de los resultados a mostrar]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: El código se comparte como texto, así como nadie te va a responder con imágenes para que tengas que transcribir (y en tu caso, además, son ilegibles). Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, la función para crear las tablas y pintarlas de manera única es la siguiente:

```
static public function createTable($rows, $tables, $countComb, $output) {

        $count = 1;
        $s = '';
        $celdas=$rows;
        
        $dato=[[]];
        $long=0;
        $col=0;

        /*=============================================
        Obtenemos las combinaciones y las guardamos en un arreglo
        =============================================*/
        for ($t=0; $t<$countComb ; $t++) {

            for ($x=0 ; $x<$celdas; $x++) {

                $long = explode(" ", $output[$t]);
                $dato[$x][$t]=$long[$x];
                    
            }

        }

        /*=============================================
        Creamos las tablas con la cantidad de combinaciones posibles
        =============================================*/
        for ($iT=0; $iT < $tables*2; $iT++) {

            $s .= '<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 scroll article-loop">';
            $s .= '<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">';

            /*=============================================
            Creamos la cabecera
            =============================================*/
            $counter = $count++;
            $s .= '<thead>';

            $s .= '<tr>';
            $s .= '<th class="text-center col1" colspan="2">'.$counter.'</th>';
            $s .= '</tr>';

            $s .= '</thead>';

            /*=============================================
            Creamos el cuero
            =============================================*/
            $s .= '<tbody>';

            $h=0;
            $f=0;

            for ($iR=0; $iR < $rows; $iR++) {

                /*=============================================
                Creamos las filas
                =============================================*/
                $s .= '<tr>';
                $f=$iR;

                for ($m=0; $m < 2; $m++) {

                    $h++;
                    $col=$dato[$iR][$iT];

                    /*=============================================
                    Creamos las celdas y las pintamos si cumple la condicional
                    =============================================*/
                    if (($iR==$f) and ($m==$col)) {

                        $s .= '<td class="text-center color-none" style="background:none;" id="celda">&nbsp;</td>';

                    } else {

                        $s .= '<td class="text-center color-yellow" style="background:#FFFF00 !important;" id="celda">&nbsp;</td>';

                    }

                }

                $s .= '</tr>';

            }

            $s .= '</tbody>';

            $s .= '</table>';

            $s .='</div>';

        }

        /*=============================================
        Imprimimos las tablas creada
        =============================================*/
        return $s;

    }
```